# docker+sanic: curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Tags: python, docker, curl

I have a docker file which is as follows

```
FROM python:3.6.8
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
ADD local-module /app/local-module
RUN python3 -m venv /opt/venv
ADD . /app
RUN . /opt/venv/bin/activate && pip install Cython && pip install -r requirements.txt && pip install /app/local-module && rm -rf /app/local-module && python /app/setup.py install
CMD ["/opt/venv/bin/python3", "/app/module/app_runner.py", "--debug"]
EXPOSE 9000
```

```
docker build  --tag  module:v1  .
```

and here is the app_runner.py file which run the application in the server

```
from module import create_app_instance


app = create_app_instance()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

```
docker run -d -p 9000:9000 module:v1
5ac90afde3cc8dfe376d04ba4eaf0edc1611aef067651ec98218a51f600f6a76
```

following is the curl payload and response

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9000/api-end-point -d '{"key": value, ...}'
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Comment: Flask's default port is 5000, and the second `docker run -p` port number needs to match this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding `port='9000'` did the trick.

```
from module import create_app_instance


app = create_app_instance()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='9000')
```